# Convert Facebook graph Url to sdk format

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do i convert the code to the php sdk format

convert

```
https://graph.facebook.com/".$FBId."/apprequests?message=".$msg."&method=post"
```

to

```
$this->Facebook->api('/me/permissions/',POST,array(......));
```

Hope i make myself clear

Answer (score 0):

```
$that->Facebook->api('/'.$FBId.'/apprequests?message=".$msg."&method=post',POST,array(......));
```